# Strange "declare -x" output in Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, declare

So, I'm a complete newbie in Python. I'm currently learning from an Udemy course and, after installing jupyter and while trying to make the ''jupyter notebook'' command work (it always returned the error: jupyter: command not found), I probably did something I shouldn't have and now every time I open my terminal I get this:

```
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tCfOClSB1p/Render"
declare -x HOME="/Users/user"
declare -x LANG="pt_PT.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="user"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
declare -x PWD="/Users/user"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.5Iz52iBbGB/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="404"
declare -x TERM_SESSION_ID="DE54F659-7CC8-49AA-BF54-79192A35FFF5"
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/k5/yt8wjdnx01lb0fgcgm_01zx40000gn/T/"
declare -x USER="user"
declare -x XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
declare -x XPC_SERVICE_NAME="0"
```

Can someone help me? I've literally looked everywhere online and tried so many different things, but nothing seems to work (also, the only answer I found online was a bit too complex for a newbie like me to understand...)
Thanks!

Comment: How did you install jupyter?  Via conda, pip, homebrew, yum, a full Anaconda installation?

Comment: @James I installed it with pip (with the command "pip3 install jupyter")

Comment: @James I actually ended up being able to use the jupyter notebook command , but I'm still having the issue of that thing I put above showing up every time I open my Terminal

Comment: Somewhere, probably in `~/.bash_profile`, you have a command that looks like `declare -x`, possibly `declare -x $foo` (where `foo` is some undefined variable). You can delete that line.

Comment: @chepner I just pasted ~/.bash_profile in the terminal and it appeared /Users/user/.bash_profile: Permission denied. How can I fix this? So sorry if this seems so basic but I don't have much experience with python

Comment: @chepner ok, so I looked online I think I got the ~/.bash_profile to work and it this shows up:
export
PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/3.1.0/bin:${PATH}"
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"~/.bash_profile" 2L, 53C

Comment: It's not a command; it's a file to edit.

Comment: @chepner I just found a file named ''foo'' on my computer and it has the same code that appears on the terminal every time I open it. If I delete the file does that stop happening? Or do I need to modify something in the file?

Comment: That sounds like it's the output of whatever command produces what you see, not the command itself.

Comment: @chepner and do you have any idea where to find the ~/.bash_profile? because I can't seem to find it anywhere

Comment: That is the full name; `~` is your home directory. If it's not there, some other configuration file is probably responsible, but Stack Overflow isn't the place to debug this. Try apple.stackexchange.com.